# Blender particle system disintegration effect

Tags: particles

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnpOBe8X--M).

Whenever I preview the disintegration effect, I see it being done properly and it breaks into pieces of smaller sheets (above). But when I bake or export the animation, I see the pieces clump up into balls (below). Would anyone know how to fix this? I want the pieces to not clump up into smaller balls

[image: proper method]
[image: baked or rendered animation]

Comment: It looks like somehow the cloth physics is being altered, possibly because of collision calculation difference.

Comment: can you add your blend file ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help)) or at least a screen shot showing your modifier settings?